# Merging array (Laravel Collection)

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I need to join to separate arrays, I am working with Laravel 5.3 Collections. I have two separate objects. One object I am getting distance matrix from google maps between cities and street address. The end responses looks like this for example:

```
[{"distance":"14.0 km"},{"distance":"85.6 km"},{"distance":"15.9 km"}]
```

I have another response which lists the stores. The distance matrix above is relevant to each store. The store response looks like this:

```
{
    "0":{
        "id":3,
        "user_id":2,
        "brand_id":"2",
        "type":"store",
        "name":"Store One"
    },
    "4":{
        "id":6,
        "user_id":2,
        "brand_id":"2",
        "type":"store",
        "name":"Store Two"
    },
    "6":{
        "id":9,
        "user_id":2,
        "brand_id":"2",
        "type":"store",
        "name":"Store Three"
    }
}
```

I need to join `each`  distance item into each store but I am having trouble combining the both. Basically I need the array to look like this:

```
{
    "0":{
        "id":3,
        "user_id":2,
        "brand_id":"2",
        "type":"store",
        "name":"Store One",
        "distance":"14.0 km"
    },
    "4":{
        "id":6,
        "user_id":2,
        "brand_id":"2",
        "type":"store",
        "name":"Store Two",
        "distance":"85.6 km"
    },
    "6":{
        "id":9,
        "user_id":2,
        "brand_id":"2",
        "type":"store",
        "name":"Store Three",
        "distance":"15.9 km"
    }
}
```

Any help or assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

try collection `zip()` [method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-zip)

```
$distance = collect(["distance" => "14.0 km"]);

$zipped = $distance->zip($stores);

$zipped->all();
```